# How can I attempt to load a script from a CDN and fall back to a mirror?

Tags: javascript, html, css, esp8266

I am in the process of setting up a simple web app on an ESP8266. And it works like a charm. For the UI I am using Bootstrap, which is a quite large framework. This means that it is a bit slow when serving the css file, as the storage is not that fast.

Is there a way I can on the html-page (with or without JavaScript), first try to fetch bootstrap from CDN, and if we don't have network access, fetch the mirror on the ESP?

I have no clue where to start with this. I also think it would be hard to do this using JavaScript  as this will be done after the DOM is ready. So adding a stylesheet after loading, which won't work?

Do anyone have any suggestions on how to do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use a https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/XMLHttpRequest to request the css file. If it can't be loaded, reload the page to a new one that doesn't use any external resources.

Edited to add an explanation:

First, there is no trivial way to detect if a link element has finished loading a css file or if it failed. So, the easiest way for your case is to do as I mentioned, you do the XHR, if the file successfully loads, then you have network access, else you don't. There is no problem in loading 2 times, one from the XHR and other from the link tag, because, if your script loads it first, then it will be cached for the link tag, and if the link tag loads it first, then it will be cached for the XHR. So all good.

After this, if it failed to load, you would want to load it from a different location. Dynamically loading css is possible, but I thought that the simplest solution would be to just load a different page. This way, even if in the future you add more resources, more css files or some external libraries, you will always have the 2 versions of the page, the local and the network one, and no changes to do to the network not available system.

Comment: Awesome, but i of course get the "Access-Control-Allow-Origin" error. Any ideas?

Comment: If you get the access-control-allow-origin, then the file is loading! try/catch it

Comment: Forget about the try / catch, my bad, but the file would be loading in that case

Comment: Haha, i implemented this and it is obviously working :P But i don't believe it could be the only/best solution XD

Comment: Checking reliably if CSS is fully loaded isn't easy at all, specially if you want to do it cross-browser. Some browsers allows you to add an onload / onerror to the link elements that will tell you when it finished loading and if there was an error. That would be perfect, right? But not all browsers support it. And it is not easy to figure out support... one old Safari version for example, shows that it supports it but it doesn't. Then it is possible to do polling, but polling has its own set of problems. I spent a week a couple of years ago fixing this area for a framework, it wasn't funny

Comment: In your specific case, polling document.styleSheets would be an option, but I don't even remember the problems with certain browsers for this

Comment: Ah, sorry, I indeed remember: by polling you never know if a css didn't load because it is pending or because there was an error.

Comment: So, in your case, polling might be an option, checking after, lets say 3 or 4 seconds if you have the CSS file loaded, if not reload the other page... but this doesn't sound easier than my proposed solution nor better in any way

Comment: Oh and, your case is a bit easier because you don't want to know if the css was fully loaded, you just want to know if it can be loaded. That makes a big difference, because then you can use XHR and even if you get the access-control-allow-origin, then you know it can be loaded...

Comment: I hope that after the explanation you accept that the solution is simple enough while providing a quite good cross-browser solution. If you don't care about old browsers, just add the onerror event to the link element... and that is for sure the shortest and cleanest possibility.